# should `dist-upgrade` be followed with a reboot?

Tags: maintenance, dist-upgrade

Following a periodic, in my case weekly, run of:
`apt-get update`
`apt-get dist-upgrade`
is there much benefit from rebooting?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You only need to reboot if Ubuntu tells you to, e.g. when a new kernel got installed.  (It's even possible to circumvent those reboots via e.g. [ksplice](http://www.ksplice.com/), which applies updates to the running kernel.) Otherwise there is no benefit from it. Restarting the specific application or a log out and log in often is enough to get all the benefits from updates.